# Laravel pagination link not working in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

My pagination works right at localhost but not at server.The page counts are displayed correctly, but the first page information is only displayed.

**controller :**

```
$customers = Customer::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
return view('admin.customers_list',compact('customers'));
```

**view :**

```
{{$customers->links()}};
```

**route:**

```
Route::resource('customer','Admin\CustomersController');
```

Comment: Can you just remove the space between please `$customers  ->links` ?

Comment: I think there is some problem in routes. Can you post related routes in your question and update it?

Comment: what did `dd()` return ?

Comment: Is pagination working fine on local?

Comment: dd() is die and sump means will display response @Md.SukelAli

Comment: Try creating individual function oriented routes, 1 route for 1 function instead of resource

Comment: @svikramjeet, thanks i know what it means. I wanted to know what return from `dd($customers)`. Is it return data with pagination or what ?

Comment: dd($customers):
LengthAwarePaginator {#354 ▼
  #total: 31
  #lastPage: 4
  #items: Collection {#362 ▶}
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://dashboard.advili.com/customers/show/0/all"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
}

Comment: @Md.SukelAli 
it's true?

Comment: @svikramjeet yes its works

Comment: @F.Joodaki. it's fine.

Comment: What does `the first page info is only displayed` means? What's the error?

Comment: @Md.SukelAli return($customers->links()) :
‹
1
2
3
4
›

Comment: @gbalduzzi no . everything seems to be right, but when I want to read the next page information, it also displays the front page information.

Comment: Please share the url of page 2

Comment: @svikramjeet http://dashboard.advili.com/customers/show/0/all?page=2

Comment: @F.Joodaki http://dashboard.advili.com/index.php/customers/show/0/all?page=2

Comment: So the issue is with routes , i think you are using apache then you need to update your .htaccess something like below

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @svikramjeet solved,,  thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's working fine at localhost, maybe you should check your server configuration for handling routes.

if you are using Nginx as your web server you can add these lines to your config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

And in case of using apache:

```
<Directory "path/to/your/project">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

is necessary.

I hope it would work for you

Comment: I'm using Apache but I don't know which file should be changed

Comment: please check if rewrite engine is enabled or not. and then you must write those lines in your sites-availbale/config file.